# Как снизить нагрузку на пк при запуске скрипта Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, скрипт, highload

В теме [Как получить пути до всех папок, существующих на компьютере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406886/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5) мне помогли написать скрипт, вот итоговый код:

```
import glob
import os
from win32api import GetLogicalDriveStrings
from os import walk

os.system(f'title UPX Soft by httpshotmaker')

print(
    '  __    __  .______   ___   ___         _______.  ______    _______ .___________.\n',
    '|  |  |  | |   _  \  \  \ /  /        /       | /  __  \  |   ____||           |\n',
    '|  |  |  | |  |_)  |  \  V  /        |   (----`|  |  |  | |  |__   `---|  |----`\n',
    '|  |  |  | |   ___/    >   <          \   \    |  |  |  | |   __|      |  |     \n',
    "|  `--'  | |  |       /  .  \     .----)   |   |  `--'  | |  |         |  |     \n",
    ' \______/  | _|      /__/ \__\    |_______/     \______/  |__|         |__|     \n'
    )

path = [root for drive in GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1] for root, _, _ in walk(drive)]
targetPattern = rf"{path}\*.exe"

for soft in glob.glob(targetPattern):
    os.system(f'upx --best "{soft}"')
    try:
        os.system('clear')
    except:
        os.system('cls')
```

Но в чем проблема: при запуске диски нагружаются на 100% и все зависает намертво. Как я могу снизить нагрузку на диски? Готов потратить больше времени на исполнение скрипта, главное чтобы комп не дох

Comment: Ну воткните в цикл `time.sleep` на сколько-нибудь. Хотя не уверен, что сильно поможет.

Comment: Часть кода root for drive in GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1] for root, _, _ in walk(drive) мне дали, ее я не понимаю, так бы туда засунул time.sleep

Comment: Ну вот внутрь `for` куда-нибудь, хоть первой же строкой, к примеру `time.sleep(0.05)`. Только в начале скрипта ещё сделать `import time`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я изменил следующий код:

```
[root for drive in GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1] for root, _, _ in walk(drive)]
```

На этот:

```
for drive in GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]:
    sleep(drv) #Уход в сон при смене диска
    for root, _, _ in walk(drive):
        sleep(fol) #Уход в сон каждую новую папку
        os.system(f'title UPX Soft by httpshotmaker')
        root = "".join(root)
        targetPattern = rf"{root}\*.exe"
        soft = glob.glob(targetPattern)
        if soft == list():
            continue
        if f'{os.getenv("SystemDrive")}\\Windows' in root or f'{os.getenv("SystemDrive")}\\$Recycle.Bin' in root or f'{os.getenv("SystemDrive")}\\Program Files' in root or f'{os.getenv("SystemDrive")}\\Program Files (x86)' in root or f'{os.getenv("SystemDrive")}\\PerfLogs' in root:
            continue
        i += 1
        os.system(f'title Folders found: {i}')
        for j in soft:
            clean()
            banner()
            os.system(f'upx --best "{j}"')
            os.system(f'title Working with {j}...')
        clean()
        banner()
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить задержку в цикл:

```py
import time

...
for soft in glob.glob(targetPattern):
    time.sleep(0.05) # числом можно поиграться
    ...
```

Больше задержка - меньше нагрузка на диск. Но насколько это будет равномерно - сказать сложно.

Чтобы добавить задержку в первый цикл `path = [root for drive...` перепишите это списковое сокращение в обычный цикл:

```py
path = []
for drive in GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]:
    for root, _, _ in walk(drive):
        path.append(root)
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: Зависает еще до этого, в предыдущем цикле: root for drive in GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1] for root, _, _ in walk(drive)